# Jquery/Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected End of Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I am getting this error from a jquery script on a specific page which performs an ajax call... and as far as I know it is generally an error caused by a missing } or )... but I have looked through the code over and over again and cannot see anything that is missing. Are there any other possible reasons this error could be flagged?

```
 $('#socialMedia img').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).prop('id').toLowerCase();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "./socialMedia/" + id + ".php",
                    success: function(msg) {
                            $('.socialLink').css('opacity', '0.4');
                            $(this).css('opacity', '0.9');
                            if ($('#Feed').css('display') != 'none') {
                                    $('#Feed').slideToggle(400, function() {
                                            $('#Feed').html(msg);
                                    });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    $('#Feed').html(msg);
                            }
                            $('#Feed').slideToggle(400);
//                              if ($('#'+id+'Script').length <= 0) {
//                                      $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/' + id + '.js" id="'+id+'Script"></script>');
//                              }
                            //alert(msg);
                    }
            });
    });
```

EDIT: you can "see" (you won't actually see anything as the error causes the page never to be loaded) the page by going to http://www.luketimoth.me... and then clicking "contact.me" (it is an AJAX site, and I have not yet implemented any handling of url specifiers)

Comment: Is this code the entire contents of your javascript file? And is it the only javascript file being loaded? Also, save yourself some trouble looking over and over the code. Use http://jshint.com/

Comment: This was all the JS code that was being loaded in the AJAX call, yes. Problem is sorted now, as you may see. Thanks for the link. It'll certainly come in handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the AJAX response at this URL:

http://www.luketimoth.me/pages/contact.me.php

The ending </script> tag actually causes the end of that script portion - double-slash comment syntax is for javascript, the HTML parser doesn't respect it and ends the script section right there.

Comment: Okay. That sorted that problem out. Thanks.

I am beginning to think that I ought to be loading in javascript in a different way, e.g. appending a script tag to the head on page load might be a smarter way of doing things.

Comment: Yup. I'd just stick it at the bottom, right before the closing body tag, but yeah, loading a remote file avoids the HTML parsing edge cases.